# design of mid-large sized application when doing TDD?

Tags: tdd

I have a good grasp of unit testing, DI, mocks, and all the design principal goodness required to have as close to full code coverage as humanly possible (single responsibility principal, think 'how will i test this' as I code, etc...).

My most recent app, I did not code doing true TDD. I kept unit-testing in mind as I coded, and wrote my tests after writing the code, refactoring, etc.. I did TDD when it was 'easy' to do... however I did not have as good of a grasp as I do now... That was the first project I made full use of DI, mocking frameworks, etc, and the first which had full code coverage - and I learned a lot from it as I went along.  I'm itching to get assigned to my next project so I can code it completely doing TDD from scratch.

I know this is a broad question, and I've already ordered TDD by example and XP Unleashed, but I'm hoping for a brief overview of how you all design / write a large application doing TDD.

**Do you write the entire application, using nothing but stubbed out code?** (e.g., write all the function signatures, interfaces, structures, and write the entire application but without writing any actual implementation)? I could picture it working on small-mid sized, but is this even possible on large applications?

**If not, how the heck would you write your first unit test for the highest level function in your system**? Lets say for example - on a web service where you have a function called DoSomethingComplicated(param1,...,param6) exposed to the world. Obviously, writing the test first for a simple function like AddNumbers() is trivial - but when the function is at the top of the call stack such as this?

**Do you still do design up-front**? Obviously you still want to do 'architecture' design - e.g., a flow chart showing IE talking to IIS which talks to a windows service via WCF which talks to the SQL Database... an ERD which shows all your SQL tables and their fields, etc... but what about class design? Interactions between the classes, etc? Do you design this up-front, or just keep writing stub code, refactoring the interactions as you go along, until the whole thing connects and looks like it will work?

Any advice is much appreciated

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Do I write the entire application, using nothing but stubbed out code?**

No, not in the slightest sense - that sounds like a very wasteful approach. We must always keep in mind that the underlying reason for doing TDD is **rapid feedback**. An automated test suite can tell us if we broke anything much faster than a manual test can. If we wait wiring things together until the last moment, we don't get rapid feedback - while we may get rapid feedback from our unit tests, we wouldn't know if the application works as a whole. Unit tests are only one form of test we need to perform to verify the application.

A better approach is to start with the **most important feature** and work your way in from there, using an **outside-in** approach. This often means starting with some UI.

The way I do it is by creating the desired UI. Since we normally can't develop UI with TDD, I simply create the View with the technology of choice. No tests there, but I wire up the UI to some API (preferrably using declarative databinding), and that's when the testing begins.

In the beginning, I would then TDD my ViewModels/Presentation Models and corresponding Controllers, possibly hard-coding some responses to see that the UI works. As soon as I have something that doesn't explode when you run it, I check in the code (remember, many small incremental check-ins).

I subsequently work my way **vertically** down that feature and ensure that this particular piece of UI can go all the way to the data source (or whatever), ignoring all other features.

When the feature is done, I can start on the next feature. The way I picture this process is that I fill out the application by doing one vertical slice at a time until all features are done.

Kick-starting a greenfield app this way always takes extra **long time for the first feature** since this is where you have to wire up everything, so pick something simple (like the initial View of the app) to keep things as simple as possible. Once the first feature is done, the **next ones become much easier** because the foundations are now in place.

**Do I still design up-front?**

Not much, no. I normally have an overall design in mind before I start, and when I work in a team, we sketch this overall architecture on a whiteboard or a slide deck before we start.

This is more or less limited to

- The number and names of layers (UI, Presentation Logic, Domain Model, Data Access, etc).
- The technologies used (WPF, ASP.NET MVC, SQL Server, .NET 3.5 or whatnot)
- How we structure production code and test code, and which test technologies we use
- Quality requirements for the code (pair programming, static code analysis, coding standards, etc.)

The rest we figure out as we go, but we use many ad-hoc design sessions at the whiteboard as we go along.

Comment: Thanks for the great & detailed response. It sounds a lot like how I coded my last app.. (except I 'cheated' on writing the tests first in most places) Perhaps transition from unit-testing to TDD doesn't really change the way I design & architect much as I thought... So I have to ask - are you very strict with doing tests first? Ever find that simply, it's just easier to write the code before the test? If so, how common does this happen? And in any specific patterns / situations?

Comment: I'm very strict when it comes to test-first, since I find that the *Red* phase of Red/Green/Refactor is very important - I've often written a test that turned out to go green right away, despite the opposite intention. This means that the test doesn't test what I thought it was testing, so it has to be rewritten. This happens to me approx. once a day, but this safeguard is not available when you write the tests afterwards. Very rarely I spike without testing, but when that happens, I delete the spike code when I'm done, and then TDD the correct implementation based on my spike experience.

Answer (score 20):

- Do you do design up front?

Of course you do.  You've got a big application in front of you.  You've got to have some idea of the structure it will have before you start writing tests and code. You don't have to have it all worked out in detail, but you should have some basic idea of the layers, components, and interfaces.  For example, if you are working on a web services system, you ought to know what the top level services are, and have a good first approximation of their signatures.

- Do you write the entire application using nothing but stubbed out code?

No.  You stub things out only if they are really difficult to control in a test.  For example, I like to stub out the database, and the UI.  I will also stub out third party interfaces.  Sometimes I will stub out one of my own components if it vastly increases the test time, or it forces me to create test data that is too complicated.  But most of the time I let my tests work on a pretty well integrated system.

I have to say I really dislike the style of testing that relies heavily on mocks and stubs.  Don't get me wrong, I think mocks and stubs are very useful for decoupling from things that are hard to test.  But I don't like writing things that are hard to test, and so I don't use a lot of mocks and stubs.

- How do you write your first unit test for a high level function?

Most high level functions have degenerate behavior.  For example, login is a pretty high level function and can be very complicated.  But if you try to log in with no user name and no password, the response from the system is going to be pretty simple.  Writing that tests will also be very simple.  So you start with the degenerate cases.  Once you have exhausted them, you move on to the next level of complexity.  For example, what if a user tries to log in with a username but no password?  Bit by bit you climb the ladder of complexity, never tackling the more complex aspects until the less complex aspects are all passing.

It is remarkable how well this strategy works.  You might think that you'd just be climbing around the edges all the time and never getting to the meat; but that's not what happens.  Instead you find yourself designing the internal structure of the code based on all the degenerate and exceptional cases.  When you finally get around to the primary flow, you find that the structure of the code you are working on has a nice hole of just the right shape to plug the main flow in.

- Please don't create your UI first.

UIs are misleading things.  They make you focus on the wrong aspects of the system.  Instead, imagine that your system must have many different UIs.  Some will be web, some will be thick client, some will be pure text.  Design your system to work properly irrespective of the UI.  Get all the business rules working first, with all tests passing.  Then plug the UI in later.  I know this flies in the face of a lot of conventional wisdom, but I wouldn't do it any other way.

- Please don't design the database first.

Databases are details.  Save the details for later.  Rather, design your system as though you had no idea what kind of database you were using,  Keep any notion of schema, tables, rows, and columns out of the core of the system.  Implement your business rules as though all the data were kept in memory all the time.  Then add the database later, once you've gotten all the business rules working.  Again, I know this flies in the face of some conventional wisdom, but coupling systems to databases too early is a source of a lot of badly warped designs.

Comment: "Please don't create your UI first". I strongly disagree. Without (static) UI first you may be just coding wrong thing. Another good read: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/04/ui-first-software-development.html

Comment: Another good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554419/when-i-proceed-to-develop-a-software-ui-design-or-database-design-which-should

Answer (score 1):

+1 Good question

I truly don't know the answer, but I would start with building blocks of classes that I could test then build into the application, not with the top-level stuff.  And yes I would have a rough up-front design of the interfaces, otherwise I think you would find those interfaces changing so often as you refactor that it would be a real hinderance.

TDD By Example won't help I don't think.  IIRC it goes through a simple example.  I am reading Roy Osherove's The Art of Unit Testing and while it seems to comprehensively cover tools and techniques like mocks and stubs, the example so far seem also pretty simple and I don't see that it tells you how to approach a large project.

Answer (score 1):

- **Do you write the entire application, using nothing but stubbed out code?**

To test our systems we mainly do unit, integration and remote services testing. In unit tests we stub out all long running, time consuming, and external services, i.e. database operations, web services connection or any connection to external services. This is to make sure that our tests are fast, independent and not relying on the response of any external service to provide us quick feedback. We have learnt this the hard way because we do have some tests that do database operations which makes it really slow that goes against the principle "Unit tests must be fast to run"

In integration tests, we test the database operations but still not the web services and external services because that can make the test brittle depending on their availability and we use autotest to run the tests in the background all the while we are coding.

However, **to test any kind of remote services**, we have tests that connect to the external services, do the operation on them and get the response. What matters to the test is their response and their end state if it is important for the test. The important thing here is, we keep these kind of tests in another directory called remote (that's a convention we created and follow) and these remote tests are only run by our CI (continuous integration) server when we merge any code to the master/trunk branch and push/commit it to the repo so that we know quickly if there has been any changes in those external services that can affect our application.

- **Do I still design up-front?**

Yes but we don't do big design up front basically what uncle Bob (Robert C. Martin) said.
In addition, we get to the whiteboard before immersing ourself into coding and create some Class Collaboration Diagrams just to make it clear and sure that everyone in the team is on the same page and this also helps us to divide the work amongst the team members.